# Order of fields in a group by clause

Tags: sql, group-by

In sql, if I have multiple columns in the group by clause, does it make a difference in which order I specify them?
For example:

```
select col1,col2, col3,sum(col4) from table1 group by col1,col2, col3?
```

Is it same as:

```
select col1,col2, col3,sum(col4) from table1 group by col2,col1, col3?
```

Comment: it the same in T-SQL

Comment: In some platforms it may change the order of results if you don't explicitly set an `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **No.**

The order doesn't matter for the GROUP BY clause. As SQL is declarative. So it doesnt matter in which order you specify the columns in `group by` clause.

In MySql if you are using `WITH ROLLUP` then the order of group by may matter otherwise it will not. In SQL Server `ROLL UP` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The order of `group by` list do not matter.
You can interpret `order by` clause as `build groups` clause,  that ensures that any one of its groups is at least in a field different from all others.
In this concept, order do not matter, the field list are just the "knives" that break apart the recordset.
Also I warn you: `group by` may or may not return records as its list says (it is not waranted). If a order (in the full output recordset) is needed, also use `order by`